# Prove that $f$ is integrable

Tags: analysis, integration

Let $f\colon A=[0,1]^2\to\mathbb R^3$, where $f$ is defined as:

$f(x,y) = 0$ if $x$ or $y$ is irrational.

$f(x,y) = 1/n $ if $y$ is rational and $x=m/n$ with $m$ and $n$ coprime integers.

I have to verify that $f$ is integrable on $A$.

I know that I have to argue in terms of upper and lower sums, so I have to see that $S(f,P)-s(f,P)< \varepsilon $ taking some partitions $P$.

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you considering Riemann integrability or Lebesque one?

Comment: Riemann integrability

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

How big is the set of discontinuities? Is your function bounded?